# data tables not posting all the selected items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

[image]

I have this `datatable` with `checkboxes` when i try to post selected values from 1 page no issues.

but when i check few `checkboxes` from page 1 and few from page 2 it only post values from the current page (the page i am currently viewing)

before posting the values i have checked with jquery it is counting correct number of selected rows.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
          $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        } );

        $('#button').click( function () {
          alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
          alert($(".messageCheckbox").is(":checked").val())
        } );
      } );
```

Filling datatables from database

```
<td><input type="checkbox"  name ="multi[]" value="<?php echo $row['work_id']; ?>"></td>
```

[image]

**PHP**

```
$aDoor = $_POST['multi'];

  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any Image.");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);

   for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
 // do stuff
} }
```

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529090/get-hidden-row-content-from-datatable-and-submit-it-along-with-the-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
      $('#button').click(function(){
        var val = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
alert(val.length);
      });
    });
```

Comment: i wanted the value of check box , `alert($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $($(this),table.fnGetNodes()).toggleClass('selected');
        //$(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
        alert($(".messageCheckbox").is(":checked").val())
    });
});
```

Here `table.fnGetNodes()` will return all the nodes inside table.

**UPDATE**

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]',table.fnGetNodes()).prop('checked',true);
    });

    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert( $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked',table.fnGetNodes()).length +' row(s) selected' );
        alert($(".messageCheckbox").is(":checked").val())
    });
});
```

Comment: so you want to select the checkbox not the row?

Comment: Yes.. my checkboxes have values which i will going to process after post

Comment: also you want to select the row? i mean adding `selected` css to row?

Comment: Nope, refer new screen shot i posted , `html source` i have id as an value, i need to get those ids

Comment: if in case you use any plugins like `uniform` then you should run an `uniform update` to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

Try this it will work.